# Open Search Server set timeout

Tags: web-crawler, search-engine, screen-scraping, open-search-server

I am using the web crawler in OpenSearchServer and while crawling, it gets stuck during the `Extracting url list` action. It also gets stuck at times when finishing a session. Is there anyway to set a time limit or a timeout so it aborts if something takes too long to run?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the default web template. In this case each time a crawl session ends, OpenSearchServer build the autocompletion index, even if you abort the session.

To avoid that, go in the panel "/Crawler/Web/Crawl process" and select the blank job.

[image: OpenSearchServer web crawler]